# How to efficiently load thousands of HD photos into pandas df and convert to HDF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, image-processing

I want to load thousands of animal images into a pandas df, add features and maybe convert to HDF.

I tried the following approach using `cv2.imread()`

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def images_to_hdf(folder_path, label):
    """
    Save a folder of images to hdf format.
    Args:
        folder_path: Path to folder containing images.
        label: A string of the image content.
    Return:
        None
    """
    image_data = [np.array(cv2.imread(folder_path + img)) for img in os.listdir(folder_path)]
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    data['Images'] = image_data
    data['Label'] = label
    data.to_hdf(path, key)
```

But it's taking longer than 1 minute for reading only 100 images plus an error(too much numerical value to store...) and I'm sure that's a very inefficient way of doing it.

I tried `np.fromfile()` instead of `cv2.imread()` it's ultra fast in comparison(I'm not really sure what it does) but it returns rank1 arrays and I want to have image 3 dimensional data stored in a pd dataframe to add labels which I'll be using to train a classifier and I'm thinking this might be a way of doing it.

Comment: which classifier are you training? Most of modern ML libraries (`keras`, `pytorch`,...) allows reading images off of hard disks.

Comment: I'm going to use logistic regression(I'm implementing my own version for the sake of understanding how things work as I just started learning ML) do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you are starting and using logistic regression, maybe you should consider lower quality images, e.g., MNIST or Fashion-MNIST.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the LQ image approach and I want to classify animal photos, I just want to make things from scratch and make it realistic just to understand the whole process, please help me if you can with the loading images part and I would go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [h5py](https://www.h5py.org/) you can directly save your images and labels into a hdf5 file (without using pandas). Here's one example how to do it (adaptation from [here](http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/hdf5/hdf5.html)):

```
import os
import glob
import cv2
import h5py
import numpy as np

def images_to_hdf5(images_path='/path/to/images',
                   label=0,
                   hdf5_path='/path/to/hdf5_file/file.hdf5'):

    image_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(images_path, '*.jpg'))
    n = len(image_names)
    labels = [label]*n

    hdf5_file = h5py.File(hdf5_path, mode='w')
    hdf5_file.create_dataset("Images", (n, 3, 224, 224), np.int8)
    hdf5_file.create_dataset("Labels", (n,), np.int8)
    hdf5_file["Labels"][...] = labels

    for i, image_name in enumerate(image_names):
        img = cv2.imread(image_name)        
        img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))  # shape (224, 224, 3)
        img = np.rollaxis(img, 2)[None]  # shape (1, 3, 224, 224)
        hdf5_file["Images"][i, ...] = img

    hdf5_file.close()
```

To open it:

```
hdf5_file = h5py.File(hdf5_path, "r")
```

To access e.g. the first image and label:

```
hdf5_file["Images"][0]
hdf5_file["Labels"][0]
#hdf5_file.close()
```